# With dartz Option<Either<T,T>> how to set to none

Tags: flutter, dartz

I am trying to use a type of `Option<Either<T,T>` and want to set this to a `none()` but this fails the error `Invalid constant value.dart(invalid_constant)`.

How can I set a Option to a none or undefined state.

```
@freezed
abstract class InvitationsState with _$InvitationsState {
  const factory InvitationsState({
    @required String email,
    @required bool isSubmitting,
    @required bool userAlreadyInvited,
    Option<Either<IRepositoryFailure, Stream<QuerySnapshot>>> snapshotOrFailure,
  }) = _InvitationsState;

  factory InvitationsState.initial() => const InvitationsState(
        email: "",
        isSubmitting: false,
        userAlreadyInvited: false,
        snapshotOrFailure: none(),
      );
}
```

Comment: you are getting an error on this line "snapshotOrFailure: none()," ?

Comment: Exactly. Not sure why, but I am using in this project dartz the first time.

Comment: that's weird you are doing nothing wrong in the snippet you provided, maybe code generation is not working correctly, try flutter packages pub run build_runner clean
 then try generation again and tell me result

Comment: Good to know that I am not completely off the track. I found the error. I removed the `const` Keyword from the `const` from the `initial()` function. Now I don't show an error. Facepalm :)

Answer (score 0):

The issue seems rooted from using `const` since the "value" `none()` looks like to be computed during runtime and isn't counted as a valid [constant](https://dart.dev/language/variables#final-and-const).